# what is the use of the 2nd parameter of the write method of TypeAdapter class?

Tags: android, json, gson

`public abstract void write(JsonWriter out,  T value) ;`

is this method not to be empty or NULL.

if this 2nd parameter is null then it raise any exception like

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: {}. Forgot to register a type adapter?`

Comment: refer this : https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html.. I think your not registering your TypeAdapter.

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException is Thrown to indicate that the requested operation is not supported. you have to provide values for registering your type register

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that these are 2 unrelated questions/issues.
The 2nd Parameter in the method is the object you want to actually to be serialized.
If you want to create your own implementation of TypeAdapter you'll have to reify the `T` to your concrete class. See the [doc](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for a good example.

The error you see hints that you just haven't registered your TypeAdapter with the Gson instance you are using.

Comment: registerTypeAdapter() is the only way to register the typeAdapter  class